# Joining 2 nodes with angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

[Image of my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjiXh.png)

Im trying to map the categories that the user have favourited to the category node to retrieve its details.

Code for my typescript :

```
ionViewDidLoad(categorykey:string){
console.log('Hello Manage Favourite Page');
let userid = this.authData.getID();

this.favouritecategories = this.af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`)
  .map(favourites => {
    favourites.map(category => {
      let categorykey = category.$key
      console.log(categorykey);
      category.favname = this.af.database.object(`/test/${categorykey}`)
    });
      return favourites;
  });
```

Code for my Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let region of favouritecategories | async; let i = index;">

    <ion-item (click)=" category.hidden = !category.hidden; category.visible = !category.visible" detail-none><b>{{i+1}}.{{ (category.favname| async)?.name }}</b>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-down" [hidden]="category.visible" item-right></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up" [hidden]="!category.visible" item-right></ion-icon></ion-item>

</div>
```

With the above code , i only managed to retrieve the category's name but not the regions name. Anyone have any idea on how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually returned the modified map. You want to do something like the following (modified for latest AngularFire versions):

```
let listObservable = this.af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`);
// use snapshotChanges() as this contains the keys
this.favouritecategories = listObservable.snapshotChanges()
  .map(snapshots => {
    // note that we return the inner .map()!
    return snapshots.map(snap => {
      let data = snap.val();
      data.favname = this.af.database.object(`/test/${snap.key}`).valueChanges();
      // note also that we return the transformed data
      return data;
    });
  });
```

Differences from the original poster's question:

- Should use .valueChanges() to get a useful observable for ngFor ops
- $key is no longer included in data by default
- But can be obtained using .snapshotChanges()

Some other useful tips:

- Avoid sequential numeric ids (i.e. arrays) in distributed data
- Write the data how you'll read it later
- Avoid trying to make NoSQL look like SQL with lots of fkey references and artificial normalizing. Just store the names where you'll read them as a general rule.
- It's okay to denormalize data.